# Custom marker does not show anything

Tags: aframe, ar.js

I created my custom marker using AR.js Marker Training online tool. It does not work. When I put the camera in front of it, it's not showing anything.

https://glitch.com/edit/#!/root-parallelogram-ztuxw6ikci?path=index.html:17:48

Answer (score 0):

Your marker is too complex for AR JS capability now.

For my experiment and research your marker should simple as (from inner to outer)

```
[black] text/simple logo
[white background]
[black background]
[white background]
[border]
```

just like default Hiro.jpg

Another source: https://medium.com/chialab-open-source/10-tips-to-enhance-your-ar-js-app-8b44c6faffca